# Express $\log 162$ and $\log 1.35$ in terms of $a = \log 24$ and $b = \log 18$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Here's a question in my textbook:

> Express $\log 162$ and $\log 1.35$ in terms of $a$ and $b$ where $\log 24 = a$ and $\log 18 = b$.

I know in order to express $\log 162$ in the form of $xa + xb$, the equation $24^x \times 18^b = 162$ must be true. But I couldn't find such combination of $x$ and $y$.

The answer in the textbook is $\log 162 = \frac{11b - a}{5}$ and $\log 1.35 = 2b - a - 1$, but evaluating the results in backwards suggests that the process for $\log 162$ involved very large numbers.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Does log here mean $\log_{10}$?

Comment: Assuming it does, then note that factoring $162$ and $135$ just involves the primes $2,3,5$.  Since you are working in base $10$, $\log 5$ can be written in terms of $\log 2$ (why?).  So use the given information to get expressions for $\log 2$ and $\log 3$.

Comment: Yes, the $\log$ here means $\log_{10}$.

Comment: then my hint should apply.

Comment: I have tried factoring $162$, but I found it couldn't be expressed into $24^x \times 18^y$ where $x$ and $y$ are integers.

Comment: That's not what my hint suggested you try.

Comment: The base of the logarithm won't matter for $\log 162$ but it will matter for $\log 1.35$.

Comment: @lulu Sorry for the misunderstanding made just now. You meant that by expressing $\log 162$, $\log 24$ and $\log 18$ in terms of $x \log 2$ and $y \log 3$, substituting into the equation I am able to find the value for $x$ and $y$ by comparing their coefficients?

Comment: Essentially, yes.  Write $a=\log 24=3\log 2 +\log 3$ and $b=\log 18=\log 2 +2\log 3$ and use that to solve for $\log 2, \log 3$ in terms of $a,b$.   For this one, it doesn't matter what base you use.  For $135$ it does because it doesn't look like you can get $\log 5$ from the given data.  But, in base $10$, you can.

Comment: I wouldn't try to do anything with 135, because 135 is a multiple of 5 and neither 24 nor 18 have 5 in their prime factorisations. However, 1.35 = (27/2)/10, therefore log(1.35) = log(27/2) - log(10) = log(27/2) - 1. Now you just have to express 27/2 as 24^x 18^y.

Comment: @Stef I found out that $\log 5 = \log \frac{2 \times 10}{4} = \log 2 + 1 - 2 \log 2 = 1 - \log 2$, which means that it can be applied to $\log 135 = 3 \log 3 + \log 5$ to become the form where you are able to equalize the coefficients from both sides of the equation, which are evaluated to of the terms $\log 2$ and $\log 3$. It won't work with other log bases, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that:
\begin{align*}
162 & = 2 \times 3^4 \\
24 & = 2^3 \times 3 \\
18 & = 2 \times 3^2 \\
\end{align*}
Therefore $162 = 24^x 18^y$ is equivalent to:
$$2^{3x+y}\times3^{x+2y} = 2\times 3^4$$
By uniqueness of prime decomposition, this is equivalent to:
$$\left\{ 
    \begin{array}{l}
        3x+y = 1 &\\
        x + 2y = 4
    \end{array} 
\right.$$
This system has a unique solution $(x, y) = (\frac{-2}{5}, \frac{11}{5})$.

You were afraid of this process involving huge numbers. At this point if I wanted to check that I did not make any mistakes, I would indeed need to calculate large numbers, to make sure that:
\begin{align*}
162 & = 24^{\frac{-2}{5}} \times 18^{\frac{11}{5}} \\
162^5 \times 24^2 & = 18^{11}
\end{align*}
These are indeed large numbers, so I'd rather avoid this, trust my prime factorisations, and instead check that:
\begin{align*}
(2\times3^4)^5 & = (2^3\times3)^{-2} \times (2\times3^2)^{11} \\
2^5\times 3^{20} & = 2^{-6 + 11}\times 3^{-2 + 22} \\
\end{align*}
which all looks correct.

In conclusion, for any logarithm, regardless of its base:
$$\log 162 = \frac{1}{5}(-2 \log 24 + 11 \log 18)$$

Answer (score 1):

Here's my take for solving $\log 162$ after referencing various answers and hints.

$\log 162$ can be expressed in the form of $xa + yb + z$.

$$\begin{align*}
    \text{i.e. } \log 162 &= xa + yb + z \\
                 \log 162 &= x \log 24 + y \log 28 + z 
\end{align*}$$

$$\begin{align*}
    \because 162 &= 2 \times 3^4 \\
              24 &= 2^3 \times 3 \\
              18 &= 2 \times 3^2
\end{align*}$$

$$\begin{align*}
    \log (2 \times 3^4) &= x \log (2^3 \times 3) + y \log (2 \times 3^2) + z \\
    \log 2 + 4 \log 3 &= 3x \log 2 + x \log 3 + y \log 2 + 2y \log 3 + z \\
    \log 2 + 4 \log 3 &= (3x + y)\log 2 + (x + 2y) \log 3 + z
\end{align*}$$

Comparing the coefficients,

$$\begin{equation*}
\begin{cases} 
3x + y = 1 \\
x + 2y = 4 \\
z = 0 
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}$$

Solving the system of equations,

$$\begin{align*}
x = -\frac{2}{5} \\
y = \frac{11}{5}
\end{align*}$$

Substituting,

$$\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\log 162 &= -\frac{2}{5}a + \frac{11}{5}b \\
         &= \frac{11b - 2a}{5}
\end{split}
\end{equation*}$$

Thanks @Stef and @lulu!